# Is it possible to trigger during an SQL row update using Logic Apps?

Tags: sql-update, azure-logic-apps

How to trigger email upon SQL table row update ?
I want to trigger email as soon as user updates the table.
"When an item is modified (V2)" step is not working when I update the table row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible, Please make sure that based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#known-issues-and-limitations-with-triggers)

You have `A ROWVERSION or an IDENTITY column`  .

e.g:- make sure that you have a column with data type as `timestamp` .

For more information please refer this [***Microsoft Blog: Poweruser***](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/When-an-item-is-modified-v2-trigger-Flow-is-not-triggering/m-p/1371014#M82111)